# AWS Athena: Convert a comma delimited string into rows

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

In AWS Athena, I want to write a query like this:

```
SELECT some_function('row1,row2,row3');
```

And get back

```
row1
row2
row3
```

How do I do this?

I know I can write this instead, but it's less convenient for me:

```
select * from (values ('row1'), ('row2'), ('row3'))
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [split](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#split) function to convert the string to an array, and then [`UNNEST`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) to convert the array to rows.  For example:

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 'row1,row2,row3' AS data
)
SELECT value
FROM t
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(split(t.data, ',')) as x(value)
```

```
 value 
-------
 row1  
 row2  
 row3  
(3 rows)
```